# Убрать слеш в конце url и добавить .html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

Подскажите как можно убрать слеш из адресов сайта и добавить .html. Может через php или js

**Пример адресов:**

```
https://site.com/page/
https://site.com/category/page2/
https://site.com/blog/category/page3/
```

**Нужно чтобы так было:**

```
https://site.com/page.html
https://site.com/category/page2.html
https://site.com/blog/category/page3.html
```

Этот вариант удаляет слэш, а как добавить html не знаю

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: так ваш htaccess в студию.

Comment: @teran добавил)

Comment: заменить `(/)` на `\.html` в последней строке и убрать `R=301`. Ваша задача вообще какая? сделать так чтобы из `xxx/` в браузере было перенправление на `xxx.html`, или чтобы при заходе на `xxx.html` открывалось. то что по работало как `xxx` ? это две обратные задачи почти

Comment: сделать так чтобы из xxx/ в браузере было перенправление на xxx.html

Comment: тогда `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ $1.html [L,R=301]` видимо

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сделать в программе, а не на сервере, то примерно так на PHP:

```
function fixUrl(string $url): string
{
    if ('/' === substr($url, -1)) {
        $url = substr($url,0,-1);
    }
    return $url . '.html';
}
```